# dimmer with neutral wire (not a smart dimmer)

Tags: dimmer-switch, neutral

I have a Lutron Diva dimmer, gray color, that was installed by a manufacturer in 2016 to operate some [fancy expensive] LED ceiling lights.

this dimmer is not a smart dimmer, has no light to it, but has a white neutral wire connection to it.    Any other non-smart dimmer on depot/lowes shelves (lutron/leviton) does not have a neutral wire connection.  what's its purpose here on this gray lutron diva dimmer I have?  I don't know if the switch got thrown out yet so i don't have the model # of it.

someone explain *forward-phase* and *reverse-phase* dimming...

https://support.lutron.com/us/en/product/casetawireless/article/product-selection/Cas%C3%A9ta-Wireless-In-Wall-Dimmers

Comment: Is it a neutral wire or a white wire being used as a hot(it should be marked black or red)?  Neutral must be white, but white does not mean it is neutral.  I think by 2016 code required a neutral to be in the switch box, usually capped and wasted, but you should also have a black and red wire in the box also.  Black and red connected to the switch.

Comment: @crip659 but even in 2016, if it was an old box it could have a switch loop. Another possibility is a 3-way switch - at least some of the current Lutron Diva dimmers have the same SKU for single and 3-way applications.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   I took manufacturer as the builder of the house.  It could be the manufacturer of the lights but seems odd.

Comment: manufacturer of a mobile office, it is definitely neutral; black hot, red to light, many whites tied together and one coming off to dimmer, green ground not connected to dimmer.  If I remember there was no provision on the dimmer to connect the ground.  I came across something about "forward phase dimming"  ?

Comment: With metal boxes, the ground wire/connection usually supplied by the screws.  Most switches also have a green screw/wire for ground, if used in plastic boxes.  LED dimmers are a different type from older types, so the neutral might do something.

Comment: Can you post the Lutron model number, or a photo of the dimmer's labeling, please? The Lutron dimmers come in various models within a given product line to accommodate various types of lights, and some of them require a neutral...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Your [3-way](https://assets.lutron.com/a/documents/030999b.pdf) comment should be an answer.

Comment: switch got thrown out before i could get a magnifying glass to read anything more than "lutron diva" on it.  But  it is not 3-way, has something to do with specific model of dimmers being better at dimming problematic loads:  https://forums.lutron.com/showthread.php/16671-Some-kits-require-a-neutral-wire-others-don-t

Comment: *The most common technology used to produce reverse
phase controls are MOSFETS. In this type of dimming,
two MOSFETS act as switches, one on each of the positive
and negative half cycles. Due to the use of MOSFETS in
the design, reverse phase dimmers generally require a
neutral wire for operation.*

Answer (score 2):

so what i had was a reverse-phase dimmer,
this pdf from Leviton explains it

https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/Dimmer-Forward-and-Reverse-Application-Note.pdf

> The most common technology used to produce forward phase controls is Triac based dimming. In this type of dimming, a semiconductor acts as a switch, controlling both positive and negative half cycles. Due to the nature of how the triac works in forward phase, it is not interrupting current at the end of the cycle, but rather letting the signal go to zero.

> Reverse Phase (Electronic Low Voltage) Controls Reverse phase controls modulate the input power by turning ON in the beginning of the cycle and turning OFF in the middle of the cycle. In order to increase the light output, the power would be turned OFF later; and to decrease the light output, the power would be turned OFF earlier.  The most common technology used to produce reverse phase controls are MOSFETS. In this type of dimming, two MOSFETS act as switches, one on each of the positive and negative half cycles. **Due to the use of MOSFETS in the design, reverse phase dimmers generally require a neutral wire for operation.**

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing I was suspecting myself